# Exoplayer FFmpeg support

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer, android-ffmpeg

I am using Android-FFmpeg .aar file from[Android-FFmpeg](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) for loading FFmpeg binaries. Is there any way to link the ffmpeg command line output from that module to exoplayer so that it streams the video with out saving the video. Otherwise should i have to develop some FFmpeg decoder to decode video as an extension to exoplayer using Media Codec Renderer?